# Create timestamp manually ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How do I do that ?

> ## You may need to initially run the command for currentTimestamp manually and redirect it to /home/steam/exiles/lastUpdate

```
#!/bin/sh
# NOTE: app_info_print/update uses the cache rather than pulling new information. Probably unintended. Definitely not useful for this application.
# Hence we need to delete the appcache to force a refresh
# On our system, the appcache can be found in /home/steam/Steam/appcache

# Delete appcache
rm -rf /home/steam/Steam/appcache/

# Pull new info and compare new timestamp to saved timestamp
# You may need to initially run the command for currentTimestamp manually and redirect it to /home/steam/exiles/lastUpdate
currentTimestamp=$(/home/steam/steamcmd/steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +app_info_update 1 +app_info_print 443030 +quit | grep -EA 1000 "^\s+\"branches\"$" | grep -EA 5 "^\s+\"public\"$" | grep -m 1 -EB 10 "^\s+}" | grep -E "^\s+\"timeupdated\"\s+" | tr '[:blank:]"' ' ' | awk '{print $2}')
lastTimestamp=$(cat /home/steam/exiles/lastUpdate)

if [ $currentTimestamp -gt $lastTimestamp ];
then
        /home/steam/exiles/updateconan.sh
        echo "$currentTimestamp" > /home/steam/exiles/lastUpdate
fi
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: What is the output of steamcmd.sh? Same as `date +%s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you only need to create the file `/home/steam/exiles/lastUpdate` with a single zero (`0`) on a line of its own.

The script is a bit lazy. It could easily have detected that the file did not exist and just insert a zero there.

A value of zero will trigger the if-statement, which will insert a proper timestamp (presumably proper, that is).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It did work - At first I tried to create the file without the "0". Sometimes things are easier than they seem to be

Comment: @SaeSi The zero needs to be there for the comparison in the if-statement to work.

Comment: Okay it didn't quite work :(. It should just do the update if necessary but right now it always does the update (restart). It does not edit my lastUpdate file once I have done a manual update (./updatechecker) The goal is to use a crontab if it works.

Comment: @SaeSi That's another issue with this script; of course the current timestamp will _always_ be greater than the last-update-timestamp... at least if it's a timestamp with to-the-second resolution.

Comment: The goal of the script is to update if necessary. It is not written by myself though but it should work. Scripts used : https://ufile.io/a22a1 and https://ufile.io/fc6b51 Guide used: http://steamcommunity.com/app/440900/discussions/0/133256240745218195/  For reference look at automating check if ....

Comment: Nevermind, it did work now. (as far as I can tell)